# How to use law of total expectation to show $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X,Z] = \sum_{w \in \mathcal{W}} \mathbb{E}[Y\mid X,Z,W=w]\mathbb{P}(W=w\mid X,Z)$?

Tags: probability

I am wondering how I can show for discrete random variables $Y, X, Z, W$ that:

$$
\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X,Z] = \sum_{w \in \mathcal{W}} \mathbb{E}[Y\mid X,Z,W=w]\mathbb{P}(W=w\mid X,Z)
$$

I am trying to use the law of iterated expectations and total probability, but am unable to get the right form. Is it because I am abusing notation on the conditional? (which should be conditioned on a value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is fine. If you understand $E[Y] = \sum_{w \in \mathcal{W}} E[Y \mid W=w] P(W=w)$ holds for any [discrete] random variables $Y$ and $W$, then you are done.

In the original question, conditioning just changes the probability distribution of $Y$ and $W$, and is notated using $P(\cdot \mid X, Z)$ and $E[\cdot \mid X, Z]$. You can then apply the law of total expectation.

Comment: Thanks! For the equation $E[Y] = \sum_{w \in \mathcal{W}} E[Y \mid W=w] P(W=w)$, is there a special name for it? Or is it something independently proved?

Comment: Yes. It is the **Law of Total Expectation**: $$\mathsf E(Y) ~{=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid W))\qquad\text{in general}\\= \sum_{w\in\mathcal W}\mathsf E(Y\mid W=w)\mathsf P(W=w)\qquad\text{for discrete random variables}}$$